# Applescript, preform certain action on a certain day

Tags: applescript, dayofweek

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to have a script run to check the day and if its monday copy, for example, cell A1, and if its tuesday copy cell B2, so on and so forth.

Comment: If you save your script as an application, you can use Calendar to launch your app at a given event: create the event, repeat it weekly and set the alert to "Custom"  and select "Open file" and below select "Other…" and in the open dialog select your script-application.

Comment: I'd go for this one, because it gives a nice balance between investment of time to make something work, and end result, you can just make an applet, that runs the script, to simulate the calendar event firing when you test it your script. @Zero: I'm into the idea of having one app fire all "script events" of Calendar, so I concentrate every thing into the app, and saves the number of different calendar events, into say 3 that fires daily. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, but it is a two-step process.  Once you have an AppleScript that works the way you like, you design a [Launch Daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) that fires every Monday, and it will run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Create an 'on idle' script that runs every 24 hours. Save this script as a 'stay open' application.

```
on idle

    -- Set variable d to the current date
    set {weekday:d} to (current date)

    -- Check if current date is equal to monday
    if d is equal to "mon" then
        -- Do your actions here
    end if

    -- Run this script every 86400 seconds (one day)
    return 86400

end idle
```